# Сериализация java

Tags: java

Есть задача: 
Необходимо написать класс который сериализует/десериализует Java Beans.
В случае наличия циклических ссылок выкинуть exception. Класс должен имплементировать следующий интерфейс:

```
interface SuperEncoder {
        byte[] serialize(Object anyBean);
        Object deserialize(byte[] data); 
}
```

класс который сериализует/десериализует написал, сложность с тем, как реализовать данный интерфейс не используя стандартный Serializable, Externalizable. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: к описанию класса, который сериализует/десериализует, добавьте "implements SuperEncoder" .

Comment: пишите, что вам мешает

Comment: Сериализуйте в текстовый файл. Например при помощи [json](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)